# What should I use to filter backbonejs Collection on server?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to filter my backbone Collection on server side?

Current I pass query params via data:

```
Books.fetch({data: {published: true, page: 3}})
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Be less vague, what do you mean "filter" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Books.filter(function (book) {
  return filterCondition(book);
}).fetch();
```

Filter your collection to the books you want, then invoke fetch on the new collection.

Comment: As I understand filter will work on client side. It won't send querystring parameters to server. But I want a server side filter.

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov is your server node.js running backbone? If so you can do the same on the server

Comment: No, Im using Rails. I want backbone to produce some parameters that could be passed to server and used for filtering.

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov why doesn't passing `{ data: ... }` work? It should unless you need to `emulateJSON` for your server